# Combining multiple Pandas data frames based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Suppose I have multiple Pandas data frames, each with multiple rows and columns, the first of which contains the ID of something. What I'd like to do is pretty simple what I failed using merge, join, concat etc... If the first column of df1 and df2 is the same, then append column 2 till the end of df2 to df1, otherwise skip it.

For instance:

```
dat1={'A':['1', '2', '3'],'B':['4', '7', '11'],
  'C':['5', '8', '12'],'D':['6', '9', '13']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dat1, orient='index')
dat2={'A':['1', '2', '3'],'B':['4', '7', '11'],
  'C':['5', '8', '12'],'D':['6', '9', '13']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dat2, orient='index')
```

In this case, since the first column in both contains A,B,C and D, then the merged data frame would have 4 rows and a total of 6 columns.

```
df_merged
   0  1   2  3  4   5
A  1  2   3  1  2   3
B  4  7  11  4  7  11
C  5  8  12  5  8  12
D  6  9  13  6  9  13
```

If instead of B in the second data frame there was an E, then I would not merge them at all.

Comment: Desired output?

Comment: The `df_merged` I wrote in the question.

Answer (score 0):

use merge

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True,right_index=True)

    0_x 1_x 2_x 0_y 1_y 2_y
A   1   2   3   1   2   3
B   4   7   11  4   7   11
C   5   8   12  5   8   12
D   6   9   13  6   9   13


def myFunc(df1,df2):
    if len(np.intersect1d(df1.index.values, df2.index.values)) == len(df1.index.values) & len(np.intersect1d(df1.index.values, df2.index.values)) == len(df2.index.values):
        df = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True,right_index=True)
        return df
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you, but If I then encounter a data frame with different row indices (the A, B, C and D), then it will take the intersection. I need it to skip that data frame instead.

Comment: @sensitive_scientist so why not just write a condition? Something like if the indexes are the same then merge else pass

Answer (score 0):

with pd.concat, When gluing together multiple DataFrames and then concat them on axis you desired, From [pandas Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

```
>>> frames = [df1, df2]

>>> pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
   0  1   2  0  1   2
A  1  2   3  1  2   3
B  4  7  11  4  7  11
C  5  8  12  5  8  12
D  6  9  13  6  9  13
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I want really. It introduces NaNs if in the list I insert a third data frame with different row indices. This third data frame should be concatenated if and only if the firs column matches.

Comment: @sensitive_scientist, that will be there but if its similar what df1 or df2 then will work, please add the another column in your example you want to add..